# MinGw compiler errror - collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

I'm trying to compile c++ in **Sublime text**. I've managed to install the the relevant packages for the **MinGw** on my computer. As well as creating a path file in the System environment variables under the directory **C:\MinGW\bin**, its exact location. And subsequently generated a new build system in the editor, containg  the fallowing:

```
{
"cmd" : "gcc $file_name -o ${file_base_name} && ${file_base_name}",
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell": true,
"working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

I went further to check in cmd  if my installation of the compiler was done properly, and it was.

```
>gcc --version
gcc (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I typed in sublime this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"hello world";
}
```

The compiled result was this :

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\44750\AppData\Local\Temp\ccVYP6T2.o:item.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `std::cout'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\44750\AppData\Local\Temp\ccVYP6T2.o:item.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\44750\AppData\Local\Temp\ccVYP6T2.o:item.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\44750\AppData\Local\Temp\ccVYP6T2.o:item.cpp:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 0.8s]
```

Comment: Build C++ with g++, not with gcc.

Answer (score 1):

You set `gcc` as the compiler, but you are building [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Building with `gcc` may allow it to *compile* the C++, but it will not automatically link in the required standard library -- which results in the failed link errors that you are experiencing.

Either change the `cmd` to use `g++`, or add the flag "`-x c++`" so that it knows that this is C++ code, which should allow it to pull in the correct libraries.

Comment: Whoops, missed that -- thanks for pointing it out. Updated.

Comment: Just tried to use c and keeping the same aspects as mentioned before and still got the same error : ` #include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   // printf() displays the string inside quotation
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
} ` and got this `The system cannot execute the specified program.
[Finished in 3.4s with exit code 1]
[cmd: gcc saacs.c -o saacs && saacs]`

Comment: Could i possibly just delete the compiler all together and install a new one

Comment: You can get a standalone version from http://winlibs.com/ that requires no installation. Just unzip it. This way you can try it out without deleting your old compiler (just make sure to not mix paths).